# Why are all policemen rhinos?

Tags: analysis, sing

All the policemen and prison guards in [Sing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3470600/) seem to be rhinoceroses. The only exception I noticed are the pilots of police helicopters that are pigs. As far as I can tell other professional and social groups consist of animals of different species, so why the exception for the police force? Is it a reference to some American stereotype?

Comment: My guess is because rhinos are seen as tough, fierce creatures that should be respected. They're also very large and intimidating when used as characters. As prison guards and policemen, you want that these types of features.

Comment: Kung fu Panda reference?   I've never heard of rhino's being used as a stereotype.   "He's a rhino" isn't something people would say though I suppose it could mean strong and a little dumb, but it's not used.   Rino is used to describe a republican who sometimes votes with the left.

Comment: @DustinDavis That makes sense, the problem is that, as I mentioned in my question, I didn't notice any other monospecies group. Taking this into account I would rather expect the police force to consists of animals of many different tough and fierce species, yet it seems that for some reason they chose to make an exception and used rhinos only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probably budget reasons.**

The film had a 75 million dollar budget, 15% of which went to acquiring the rights to songs used. For comparison, Coco cost 175 million; Finding Dory cost 200 million; Moana, Frozen and Zootopia cost 150 million; and Tangled cost $260 million.

If you're operating on a smaller budget, it makes sense to reuse character designs and their corresponding models and textures wherever it doesn't impact the story. The police force is secondary to the main plot, and are already somewhat of a uniform group, so they're a logical group of characters to save money on. My guess is that the helicopter pilots are pigs because it was easier to model and animate a pig piloting a helicopter than it would have been to make a rhino do it.